# Mysql query to add column to

Tags: mysql

Good Day

Hoping you can assist as I am unable to figure this out with my noob brain. :)

I have a sql query.

```
SELECT 
  i.cOurRef as 'IR Number',
  date(i.dCreated) as 'Date Created',
  a.cDisplayName as 'Logged To',
  c.Name as Client,
  i.cOutline as Description,
  date(i.dDueBy) as 'Due date'

FROM
_rtblIncidents i

left join 
_rtblagents a on
    i.iCurrentAgentID = a.﻿idAgents

left join client c on 
    i.iDebtorID = c.﻿DCLink

where iIncidentStatusID <> '3' and iIncidentTypeID in (11,75) and 
  iCurrentAgentID in (285,284,266,55,113,282,190,293)
```

this part works correctly. and produces the desired output.

```
IR Number   Date Created    Logged To   Client  Description Due date
IR00032     2018/11/20      Eng 1       client 1    Desc 1  2018/12/07
IR00033     2018/12/06      Eng 2       client 2    Desc 2  2018/12/07
IR00034     2018/12/06      Eng 3       client 3    Desc 3  2018/12/07
IR00035     2018/12/05      Eng 4       client 4    Desc 4  2018/12/06
IR00036     2018/12/03      Eng 5       client 5    Desc 5  2018/12/07
IR00037     2018/11/26      Eng 6       client 6    Desc 6  2018/12/05
```

What I am trying to do is add another column to the output that would show the "age of the request in days after Due Date. My query to do this works well on its own.

```
SELECT 

DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE(dCreated)) AS 'Ticket Age'

FROM _rtblIncidents
```

and works to calculate the days.

```
Ticket Age
   63
   37
   28
   21
   17
   17
```

I have tried to union the queries but that doesn't work mysql complains that the 2 queries have different number columns.

Any and all assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: _Don't_ use single quotes as alias names.  Single quotes should only be used for string literals.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use sub select query to calculate field as well.

```
SELECT 
i.cOurRef as 'IR Number',
date(i.dCreated) as 'Date Created',
a.cDisplayName as 'Logged To',
c.Name as Client,
i.cOutline as Description,
date(i.dDueBy) as 'Due date',
(SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE(i.dCreated))) AS 'Ticket Age'

FROM
_rtblIncidents i

left join 
_rtblagents a on
i.iCurrentAgentID = a.﻿idAgents

left join client c on 
i.iDebtorID = c.﻿DCLink

where iIncidentStatusID <> '3' and iIncidentTypeID in (11,75) and 
iCurrentAgentID in (285,284,266,55,113,282,190,293)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - just simply add the calculated filed in select list

```
SELECT 
  i.cOurRef as 'IR Number',
  date(i.dCreated) as 'Date Created',
  a.cDisplayName as 'Logged To',
  c.Name as Client,
  i.cOutline as Description,
  date(i.dDueBy) as 'Due date', DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date(i.dCreated)) AS 'Ticket Age'

FROM
_rtblIncidents i

left join 
_rtblagents a on
    i.iCurrentAgentID = a.idAgents

left join client c on 
    i.iDebtorID = c.DCLink

where iIncidentStatusID <> '3' and iIncidentTypeID in (11,75) and 
  iCurrentAgentID in (285,284,266,55,113,282,190,293)
```